# Saving or Using a file name that have the extension in uppercase can be a problem?

Tags: c#, file, file-extension

Recently I got a error fix that a user tried to upload a file with the name `some_name.PNG` (focus on the extension name in uppercase) and said it was a invalid file and couldn't upload.

So I realized that the validation of the file was considering only files with lower case extensions as valid file, so if I can only accept files with `.png` extension, a file with `.PNG` isn't valid.

To fix this problem, is very easy, just lower case the file extension and it's good.

But my question is, If I allow files with any letter case, is it possible to have any problems or security issues?
Is there any difference between `.png` and `.PNG` files? Or `.Png`?

**Observation**: I'm using c# backend, but my question is regardless of the language or tecnology.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem until you have a code that rely on case of extension string

Comment: Unlike Windows, filenames in *nix are case sensitive.  That's not a security issue, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems but it may complicate some of the backend code, which you are already seeing.  I would highly suggest adding code that normalizes the extensions so they are all lowercase or all uppercase.  Pick one and be consistent throughout the application.